# How can I confirm if this code blocks can verify an email once user clicks on it?

Tags: laravel

My Controller

```
class EmailVerificationLinkController extends Controller
     {
        public function update(Request $request){

         $candidate = Candidates::find($id);
         $candidate->email_verified_at = 'datetime';
         $candidate->update();

        return view('verified');
     }
}
```

**My Route**

```
Route::get('/verify', 'EmailVerificationLinkController@update');
```

**My Link**

```
<a href="/verified"">Verify email</a>
```

Here is what I have in my table..

```
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
```

My aim is for candidates to click on this link in their email and then "email_verified_at" changes value in the database to the current time or probably boolean (from false to true). Then they are linked to a new page.

Comment: where are the userId of the use you want to varify

Comment: Or you can use what exists in the documentation, instead of User model, apply it to your Candidate model: https://laravel.com/docs/master/verification

Comment: if your route name is 'verify' then to hit them need write 'verify' instead of 'verified'

Comment: @nakov, I tried applying the verification on my model but couldn't find a way. AtGauravGupta, I have changed it to verify. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller to this :

```
class EmailVerificationLinkController extends Controller{
    public function update(Request $request,$id)
     {
        $candidate = Candidates::find($id);
        $candidate->email_verified_at = now();
        $candidate->save();
        return view('verified');
    }
}
```

Your route should be like this:

```
Route::get('/verify/{id}', 'EmailVerificationLinkController@update');
```

In your view there should be candidate id parsed so that you can use like this on your link

```
<a href="/verify/{{$candidate->id}}">Verify email</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @KhalidKhan, I have changed everything as you stated and I got no error. The only thing is, when I click on the link in the email, Google shows a page with the following: This site can’t be reached      ***`www.workhere.me’s server 
    IP address could not be found.
    Search Google for workhere me verify
    ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`***

Comment: @cd4success it seems your hosting issue.try after some time or clear the cache

Comment: Does it mean that I have to be in production mode before the link can actually work?

Comment: I tried doing it manuallly and it gave this error.  ***`ErrorException
date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given`***. What should I do?

Comment: ***Thank you! Thank you!! Thank you!!! A million times @KhalidKhan***. It worked awesomely. It linked me to a new page and also verified the email in the database.

Comment: @cd4success  It's my pleasure to help you out. :)